# How can I get newly created entities with their proxy?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When I create new entities in a context, I cannot get a proxy even if I request it again. I have to dispose of the context and make a new one. Is this an expected behavior or am I doing something wrong?

```
int id = 0;
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    var A = context.People.Add(new Person{ Name = "Bob" }); // A is not a proxy
    context.SaveChanges(); // A is still not a proxy
    var B = context.People.Where(o => o.Id == A.Id).Single(); // B is not a proxy

    id = A.Id; // Keep the ID to use with a new context
}
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    var C = context.People.Where(o => o.Id == id).Single(); // C is a proxy!
}
```

Comment: Instead of `People.Add(new ...)`, try using `People.Create()`. This should give you a proxy if your POCO is defined to support proxy objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`Create`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679504(v=vs.113).aspx) method of your DBSet:

```
var newPerson=context.People.Create();
```

The instance returned will be a proxy if the underlying context is configured to create proxies and the entity type meets the [requirements for creating a proxy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd468057(v=vs.100).aspx).

### Update

As @Asad said, if you are creating a new entity, you need to add it to your DBSet after creating it:

```
context.People.Add(newPerson);
```

Or change its State to `Added`, for example:

```
context.Entry(newPerson).State = EntityState.Added;
```

And, if you are updating it, then you should use [`Attach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.attach(v=vs.113).aspx) method:

```
var existingPerson=context.People.Create();
existingPerson.Id = 1; // assuming it exists in the DB
context.People.Attach(existingPerson);
```

Comment: It is worth noting that the instance returned by `Create` is not automatically a member of the `DbSet`. This is an additional step that needs to be explicitly performed by `Attach`ing or `Add`ing it (depending on whether it is a new or existing entity).

Answer (score 2):

octavioccl's answer is correct but would force me to break my data layer pattern. I have an alternative (probably slower) solution that didn't force me to create the entity inside my repository nor required me to add mapping everywhere (or a mapping library). I am still accepting your answer since it probably is closer to best practice and did answer the original question but I wanted to add this option if ever needed.

```
dbContext.People.Add(person);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
dbContext.Entry(person).State = EntityState.Detached;
dbContext.People.Find(person.Id);
```